# C# a Dictionary Interface throws on accessing but returns false on null check? How to fix it?

Tags: c#, moq

why is this happening and how to correctly check for it ?

```
private IDictionary<string, string> knownContentTypes;

public ContentTypeDictionaryService(IDictionary<string, string> contentTypesDictionary) {
    this.knownContentTypes = contentTypesDictionary;
}

public bool TryGetExtension() {
    var a = (knownContentTypes == null); // a is false
    var x = knownContentTypes.Any(); // this throws NullReferenceException.
}
```

**EDIT** Full code:

```
public class ContentTypeDictionaryService : ContentTypeService {
    private IDictionary<string, string> knownContentTypes;
    public ContentTypeDictionaryService(IDictionary<string, string> contentTypesDictionary) {
        if (contentTypesDictionary == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("contentTypesDictionary");
        this.knownContentTypes = contentTypesDictionary;
    }

    public bool TryGetExtension(string contentType, out string extension) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType)) throw new ArgumentNullException("contentType");

        var a = knownContentTypes == null; // false
        var x = knownContentTypes.Any(); // An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (not inner exception)
        return extension != default(string);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void WeirdTest() {
    string extension;
    var contentTypesDictionaryMock = new Mock<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    contentTypeService = new Mock<ContentTypeDictionaryService>(contentTypesDictionaryMock.Object);
    contentTypeService.TryGetExtension("image/png", out extension)
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

How should I mock the dictionary? I'm using Moq.

Comment: It most certainly is not throwing a null reference exception.  You're not calling any instance method.  Either you're getting a different error, or you're using different code.

Comment: Can you add to the code so that it can be reproducible by us?

Comment: Is that possible some other thread sets `knownContentTypes` to `null`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `.Any()` is an _extension_ method, so it would not throw a `NullReferenceException` even if `knownContentTypes` _was_ null.  In that case it would throw an `ArgumentNullException`

Comment: Are you sure it's not an `ArgumentNullException`?  If `knownContentTypes` is null, you would expect an `ArgumentNullException` (because it's actually an argument to a static method).  Perhaps the NRE is being thrown elsewhere; did you modify your code for the sake of posting the example?  Was the original code an expression with more dots in it?  For example, an expression like `foo.BarDictionary.Any()` will throw a NullReferenceException if foo is null.

Comment: @DStanley I realized after reading servy's comment. I suspect OP is showing us different code.

Comment: it is NullReference. I will post full code.

Comment: I'm confused why you are using the debugger to look at the value of `a` but not to see if `knownContentTypes` is null or not

Comment: There are some very contrived possibilities, such as you using a method other than the LINQ implementation of `Any`, or your dictionary implementation returning a null enumerator, but you'd need to be more or less actively trying to break the code in those cases.

Comment: @Servy thanks to Servy answer I think the problem, since this is a mock, is the mock is returning null to get enumerator... can this be the case ?

Comment: Why mock the dictionary instead of just passing a Dictionary?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I was testing something else, I just got into this situation and I don't know what was happening. Actually my test doesn't call the mocked service but another one that uses that mocked service.

Comment: @JasonP that's what I will do. Thanks. (feels dumb)

Comment: @Servy as it turns out, you were on the right track, except in the assumption that GetEnumerator returning null implies actively trying to break the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mock is returning `null` when the extension method calls `GetEnumerator()`.

You need something like

```
contentTypesDictionaryMock.Setup(x=>x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(new DictionaryEnumerator());
```

Except replace DictionaryEnumerator() with something that exists. Alternatively don't mock the dictionary since it isn't something you are concerned about having side effects.

Comment: you are right. I updated the question for asking how to mock that correctly

Comment: not mocking the dictionary. That was stupid from my part to mock a dictionary.

Comment: @Bart you might well mock the dictionary, and return a mock enumerator.  Then you can control the behavior of the enumerator through the mocking framework.  I've done similar things in the past.

Comment: I see @phoog, in this particular case there is no point on mocking the dictionary, but I see that I might be usefull in other situations.